# How to upload multiple files using dropzone.js?

Tags: php, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js, dropzone

My problem is when I drag & drop multiple files that time each image is called a particular ajax. I want to multiple file upload time only one ajax call.

I want to choose a single file and drag & drop it in dropzone and another file drag & drop so as not to replace the file with to first one I need both theme and click on the button that time save in the folder at one time ajax call.

Here is my code

**HTML file**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/min/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.2.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <form action="route.php?actionPresubmission=loanPreSubmission" class="form-horizontal dropzone" id="imageform">
    </form>
</div>
```

**route.php**

```
$uploadDir = 'upload';
   if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tmpFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];     
    $filename = $uploadDir.'/'.time().'-'. $_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmpFile,$filename);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Not a duplicate because in my case choose one by one and send multiple files at a one time @miken32

Comment: Did you get it I'm not using any <input name="file[]" type="file" /> in my code buddy @miken32

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the question, I think you want to upload multiple files through one call.
For that, you need to stop autoProcessQueue which is true by default

**Script:**

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        autoProcessQueue: false, //This stops auto processing
        acceptedFiles:".png,.jpg", //Change it according to your requirement.
        init: function(){
            var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
            mydropzone = this;
            submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
                mydropzone.processQueue();
            });
            this.on("success", function(file,response){
               alert(response);
            });
        },
    };
```

**HTML**:

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></form>
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="submit">Upload</button>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$folderName = 'upload/';
if(!empty($_FILES))
{
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileLocation = $folderName . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($file,$fileLocation);
} ?>
```

Hope this helped you :)